# How do I call a namespaced function without evaluating the parameters you are giving it?

Tags: r

In R, the idiomatic way to call another function without evaluating the parameters you give it is apparently as follows:

```
Call <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)
# Modify parameters here as needed and set unneeded ones to NULL.
Call[[1L]] <- as.name("name.of.function.to.be.called.here")
eval.parent(Call)
```

However, when I put a namespaced name (e.g. `utils::write.csv`) in the `as.name()` call, I get an error:

> "could not find function "utils::write.csv"

What is the proper way of using this R idiom to call a namespaced function?

Comment: In R, the idiomatic way to call a function without evaluating the parameters is `f(x, y, z)`.  That's what lazy evaluation is all about!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `do.call()`, which both constructs and evaluates the function call.

Like the approach you started with, this one uses the fact that R calls are lists in which: **(a)** the first element is the name of a function; and **(b)** all following elements are arguments to that function.

```
j <- function(x, file) {
    Call <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)
    arglist <- as.list(Call)[-1]
    do.call(utils::write.csv, arglist)
}

dat <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))

j(dat, file="outfilename.csv")
```

**EDIT:** FWIW, here's an example from `plot.formula` in base R, which uses a construct similar to the one above:

```
{
    m <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
    eframe <- parent.frame()
    . . .
    . . . 
    m <- as.list(m)
    m[[1L]] <- stats::model.frame.default
    m <- as.call(c(m, list(na.action = NULL)))
    mf <- eval(m, eframe)
    . . .
    . . . 
}
```

The function uses the `do.call()` construct later on.  Going a bit deeper into the weeds, my reading is that in the snippet shown here, it instead uses several steps mostly because of the need to add `na.action=NULL` to the list of arguments.

In any case, it looks like the `do.call()` options is as close to canonical as could be desired.

Comment: This fails for me (R 2.14.0): could not find function "utils::write.csv"

Comment: @Tommy -- Thanks for catching that.  I had originally used it as a name (i.e. without quotes) and then, for some inexplicable reason edited it.  Thought I had checked that it worked both ways, but I guess not. Fixed now, though.

Comment: @Tommy -- Also, I've added an example from base R, that uses +/- the same approach as in both of our answers.

Comment: This works for me. Thanks! The do.call() version seems clearer than the eval.parent() one too.

Comment: But what does that do that `write.csv(x, file)` doesn't?

Comment: @hadley. It doesn't do anything different, or course.  I took the question to _really_ be about the mechanics of constructing calls to functions in which the 'path' is fully specified using `::` or `:::`. `utils::write.csv` was just an example. (Of course if this specificity is needed at all, it could be better solved by packaging the function and setting it up with a carefully furnished namespace...)

Comment: @hadley I use this to create a write.csv in my Rprofile that overrides row.names to be FALSE. After it does that to the arguments, it needs to call utils::write.csv to do the actual work. I omitted the row.names stuff above because it wasn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Well you can just call the function directly. No need to jump through hoops

Comment: @hadley -- Just out of curiosity, do you think that this form of call could ever be necessary?  The `plot.formula` example that I included uses an explicit path, presumably because it's a part of `namespace:graphics`, and needs to call something in `package:stats`. But do you think even that could have been better solved with proper use of namespaces?

Comment: It's completely orthogonal to namespaces. Quite a few base r functions use this technique and I don't know why. It's very rarely appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

As @Josh O'Brien answered, `do.call` is much more straight forward to use.

The first argument to `do.call` can be either a function name or an actual function. 
The function name can **NOT** contain the namespace qualifier. The `::` part is actually a function that takes the names on both sides and find the corresponding function, so it must be evaluated separately to work.

So, with `do.call`, you need something like:

```
# ...Stuff from Josh's answer goes here
# And then:
do.call(utils::write.csv, arglist)
```

And with `eval`:

```
Call <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)
# Modify parameters here as needed and set unneeded ones to NULL.
Call[[1L]] <- utils::write.csv
eval.parent(Call)
```

Note the lack of quotes around the function name. That evaluates to the function closure.

Another way of getting the function from a namespace-qualified name:

```
eval(parse(text="utils::write.csv"))
```

Again, the `::` function is called that correctly finds the function.

Another more manual way is to extract the namespace name & function name and then do the lookup yourself:

```
x <- strsplit("utils::write.csv", "::")[[1]]
get(x[2], asNamespace(x[1]))
```